# Not able to recieve message sent from mobile to GSM SIM900 but other functionalities working

Tags: arduino, iot, gsm

Not able to recieve message sent from mobile to GSM SIM900 but other functionalities working.

I think there is something related to AT command. Please help me that and thank you.

```
/*THIS TUTORIAL USED GSM SIM900A MINI V3.9.2
 
  Connect 5VT to D9 and 5VR to D10
  Feed GSM SIM900A with Arduino's 5V

  Code by IDAYU SABRI - MYBOTIC
*/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2);

// phone number
char PHONE_NUMBER[13] =  "+918380843911";

char msg;
char call;

void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600);    // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino) 
  Serial.println("GSM SIM900A BEGIN"); 
  Serial.println("Enter character for control option:"); 
  Serial.println("h : to disconnect a call"); 
  Serial.println("i : to receive a call");
  Serial.println("s : to send message");
  Serial.println("c : to make a call");  
  Serial.println("e : to redial");
  Serial.println();
  delay(100);
}

void loop()
{  
  if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 's':
      SendMessage();
      break;
    case 'c':
      MakeCall();
      break;
    case 'h':
      HangupCall();
      break;
    case 'e':
      RedialCall();
      break;
    case 'i':
      ReceiveCall();
      break;
    case 'rm' :
      ReceiveMessage();
      break;
  }
 if (mySerial.available()>0)
 Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}

void SendMessage()
{
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\""+ String(PHONE_NUMBER) +"\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("sim900a sms");// The SMS text you want to send
  delay(100);
   mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
}

void ReceiveMessage()
{
  mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); // AT Command to recieve a live SMS
  delay(1000);
  if (mySerial.available()>0)
  {
    msg=mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(msg);
  }
}

void MakeCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATD+" + String(PHONE_NUMBER) + ";"); // ATDxxxxxxxxxx; -- watch out here for semicolon at the end!!
  Serial.println("Calling  "); // print response over serial port
  delay(1000);
}


void HangupCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATH");
  Serial.println("Hangup Call");
  delay(1000);
}

void ReceiveCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATA");
  delay(1000);
  {
    call=mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(call);
  }
}

void RedialCall()
{
  mySerial.println("ATDL");
  Serial.println("Redialing");
  delay(1000);
}
```

All the connections and power supply of GSM as well as Arduino is correct.

To recive message sent from mobile to GSM and read it.

Comment: If sim-card memory for messages is full, you won't get any messages or notification . So try `mySerial.println("AT+CMGD=1,4");` to clear the sms messages first to see if the problem is related to that.